# How to enable a user-defined claim dialect in carbon/console as default

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're using WSO2 IS (Version 5.11.0).
We have composed a specific claim dialect for our needs, added it to the "claim-config.xml" file before the first server starting. The new dialect claims are mapped to the local claims.
Now we can see the new dialect and its claims in the carbon console GUI via "Main -> Identity -> Claims" menu.
But when adding new users to the system, we can't see our defined claims and their "DisplayName" in the GUI.
How can we enable our claim dialect in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server uses it's own dialect ("http://wso2.org/claims") internally and it's impossible to change this to enable a custom claim dialect. To achieve your requirement, the corresponding local claims mapped for the new dialect claims need to be enabled by default to display the attribute on the user profile. For example, if a claim in the new claim dialect is mapped to http://wso2.org/claims/nickname, then login to the management console and navigate to Claims > List > http://wso2.org/claims > Nick Name and click on Edit.  Tick **Supported by Default** check-box and Update the changes. Then this attribute will be displayed on the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dewni for your reply.
I did your suggestion and mapped my new claims to the local claims.
But unfortunately when I edit a user profile via GUI, Identity Server complains with the following error:
"One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP for user : 6c348945-bd61-4b06-b36c-fdb6a7d7807f"

Inspecting wso2carbon.log file shows:
ERR_467 The AttributeType 'groups' does not exist in the schema
ERR_467 The AttributeType 'x509Certificates' does not exist in the schema

while both of the above attributes are local claims of WSO2!

How this happens and how can I find list of the real existed attributes in the product?